# How do I check to an array of objects with the parameter start_at, which is a Datetime is before DateTime.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I have an array of array of Images that all have certain categories in an array called categories_images. Images have a start_at field, which sometimes is nil and other times is has a DateTime in them. I want the ones that have a DateTime that start prior to the current DateTime to appear on my page.

I have written the following code:

```
def now
  categories_images.select { |image| image['start_at'] }
end
```

This gives me every image that does not have nil for start_at.

So I asked:

```
def now
  categories_images.select { |image| image['start_at']  < DateTime.now }
end
```

Thinking it would give me those same images except for the ones that don't have a start_at date earlier than "Now." Instead it gives me:

```
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong? I get that this is likely ruby 102 stuff, but I'm a fresh-faced kid with dreams who could use some help. Is it saying that DateTime.now is nil so it can't inspect it? If so why, isn't that a legit method to apply to DateTime?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can change this to use both conditionals in the same block. `categories_images.select { |image| image['start_at']  && image['start_at']  < DateTime.now }` this says all the images that have a start at and where the start_at is less than now.

Comment: @engineersmnky Cool, that worked. Thanks! Now that I see it I don't know how I didn't before.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an image inside that array which has not set `start_at`.

So you can make:

```
categories_images.select do |image|
  image["start_at"] < Time.now if image["start_at"]
end
```

To only check if "start_at" is set. Because if it does not this expression will return nil, which would be interpreted as false.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, that the comparition is performed as expected unless the value is nil. That is why, you have to skip the comparitions in those cases:

```
categories_images.select { |image| image['start_at'] < DateTime.now unless image['start_at'].nil? }
```

Comment: a single line of code might solve the problem but it does not constitute an answer. Why not post some information about why this works and answer some of the questions the OP asked.